# Getting Parsing Error in XML Response From server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

The Following is my code..

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: server_url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) { 
        console.log(status);
        console.log(error);
    },
});
```

and I am always getting following error...

> parsererror
>   jQuery16402866942031674359_1433220553409 was not called
>   SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
>   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Can anybody help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: but you can't use jsonp with xml data

Comment: can you Please tell me how to do this ? without jsonp I am not getting response from server.

Answer (score 0):

According to query documentation, the first parameter ajax success method is "formatted according to the dataType parameter". You are telling it to format it as jsonp.  The contentType describes how the parameters are sent. You should set your dataType to 'xml'

Comment: then your server app probably doesn't know how to return xml data. Have you looked at the 'data' parameter to the success? log it to the console

Comment: its giving "error, 
(an empty string) " to the console. and same url is working in mobile apps Plateform.

Comment: sounds like server is returning an error. you aren't passing an parameters, should you be?

Comment: so can you help me for passing a parameter. or give me email id so I will send my script in email. can you ?

Comment: i don't know your server app. Maybe it requires POST instead of GET, or it is expecting something. One thing I know, you are trying to parse a JSON object as if it was a string. Perhaps try setting dataType to 'text'